# Convert YUV420 to BGR without using videoconvert in GStreamer

Tags: c, linux, opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am using GSteamer, and I want to convert I420 to BGR format.
Pipeline:

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location= ./Big_Buck_Bunny_1080_10s_1MB.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! fakesink`

I don't use **videoconvert** plugin because it takes many CPU workload.
I saw that avdec_h264 plugins has support BGR format and I tried to chose BGR format but the output always give I420 format ("avdec_h264 ! video/x-raw, format=BGR !").

I tried to cast it to BGR format in source code (***gst-libav/ext/libav/gstavvidec.c\gst_ffmpeg_pixfmt_to_videoformat()***) but I got an error in (gst-libav/gst-libs/ext/libav/libavcodec/decode.c), 1606

```
for (i = 0; i < num_planes; i++) {
            av_assert0(frame->data[i]);
        }
```

Does my way correct? Should I modify num_planes in deocode.c?
If it's not a right way, can I convert format by using OpenCV with GStreamer pipeline?

If you have any good way, please tell me also.

Comment: You can't get for free something that require to do some work.

Comment: Yup, so I try to make it works. :)

Comment: I mean convert from I420 to RGB (or BGR, doesn't matter) is not just name change. It's require to do some, pretty not trivial, work internally. That's why videoconvert  is mandatory. And that's why it consume CPU.

Comment: Thank RSATom, I still wonder why src pad of avdec_h264 had many color formats but it only support for YUV planar. How about calculate the image again from I420 to BGR.

Comment: The reason is simple, file can contain compressed video in different formats. The most frequently used is I420. And your mp4 has I420 inside. I mean even in compressed form, it's still I420 inside. So you just can't get something different without explicit convert. And one way to do it - use `videoconvert`.

Comment: Thanks RSATom, I got it. So, if the file contain compressed video in BGR format, the output of decoder will be BGR format. Is it right? I tried to encode raw video in BGR format and decoded again with avdec_h264 but the error print out due to "not negotiate". Anyway thank you very much for your explanation.